# Hashmap resizing implementation

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have hash map implementation in Kotlin. For some reason, after the resizing, a test case (with big quantity of elements to add) fails. When i set the size of map to a big number (without need to resize) test passes. What can be a mistake in my resize function implementation?

```
data class Entry(val key: Int, val value: Int)
const val LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75

class MyHashMap() {
    var map = arrayOfNulls<Entry>(1000)
    var added = 0

    fun resize() {
        var newMap = arrayOfNulls<Entry>(map.size*2)
        for (entry in map.filterNotNull()) {
            var index = hash(entry.key, newMap)
            newMap[probe(index, entry.key, newMap)] = Entry(entry.key, entry.value)
        }
        map = newMap
    }

    fun probe(index: Int, key: Int, m: Array<Entry?>): Int {
        var localIndex = index
        while (m[localIndex % m.size] != null) {
            if (m[localIndex % m.size]?.key == key) break
            localIndex++
        }
        return localIndex % m.size
    }

    fun put(key: Int, value: Int) {
        if (added.toDouble() / map.size >= LOAD_FACTOR) resize()
        var index = hash(key, map)
        map[probe(index, key, map)] = Entry(key, value)
        added++
    }

    fun get(key: Int): Int {
        var index = hash(key, map)
        while (map[index % map.size] != null) {
            if (map[index % map.size]?.key == key) {
                return map[index % map.size]?.value ?: -1
            }
            index++
        }
        

        return -1
    }

    fun remove(key: Int) {
        var hash = hash(key, map)
        while (map[hash % map.size] != null) {
            if (map[hash % map.size]?.key == key) {
                added--
                map[hash % map.size] = null
                break
            }
            hash++
        }
    }

    fun hash(key: Int, m: Array<Entry?>) = key % m.size
}
```

Comment: From your question, it is not clear what the failure is. Have a look at "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" specifically the Reproducible section.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment it is not clear from your description what exactly fails. One bug that may or may not be causing the failure is the way you modify `added`.

In `put()` you increment the value of `added` every time the method is called **and** you also assume that this is the number of non-null elements in the array when deciding if a call to `resize()` is needed.

That is incorrect.